# Запуск проекта из другого проекта

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

В решении есть два проекта - основной и подключенный, сторонний. Сделал в основном проекте на подключенный ссылку, добавил using, чтобы из второго вызвать форму.

```
FeatureDisplayForm fd = new FeatureDisplayForm();
fd.form = this;
fd.Owner = this;
fd.TopLevel = true;
fd.Show();
Hide();
```

Для открытия и возврата, соответственно, надо в FeatureDisplayForm объявить

```
public mainForm form;
```

Но дело в том, что второй проект не дает сделать ссылку на основной из-за возникновения цикличности, поэтому его вызвать нельзя. Как быть?

Comment: Сделайте третью сборку (проект), куда вынесите общий интерфейс.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FeatureDisplayForm : Form
{
  public Form form;
  ...
```

Comment: Нет, так работать не будет

Comment: @Mal.cev Так работать будет.